# How to retrieve and create Issues in dwg file via API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Two questions in one:

**1º Retrieve issue position, that was created in ACC Docs**

I created an Issue in a ***.dwg*** file in ACC Docs and I want to display it in my application, but the received object `issue.linkedDocuments[0].details.position` is empty:

[image: Empty position object]

There's a way to get it's position?

***2º How to create an issue to a dwg file***

I've tried to create an issue through insomnia, basically by copying almost the whole issue object that I just created in ACC, but the validation failed because I didn't pass the position:

[image: Request failed]

Good, then I passed a position inside the model "box" (I got the `viewer.model.myData` property and saw the initial and final x,y of the model), and boom, created!, but it doesn't display in ACC Docs.

Why does this divergence occur? Issues created in ACC are shown there, but they have no position, in the other hand an Issue created through API, which has position, doesn't appear, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently pushpin metadata, including the pushpin location and viewer state (camera, cut plains, selected/hidden/isolated elements), is not available for 2D CAD+PDF+Image files and the Build Sheets module through API.